# Streaming media from a remote ubuntu server to RaspBMC

Tags: ubuntu, raspberry-pi, upnp, xbmc, dlna

I am trying (without luck so far) to stream movies from a remote Ubuntu server I own to my raspberry pi running RaspBMC. The only way I could play a movie from the server so far was via SFTP which was too slow despite both my server and my home connection being 100 Mbit/s.

I tried without success to set up a mediatomb upnp server, and after that I supposedly succeeded in installing and setting up a minidlna server but I cannot connect to it as the field to enter a port in RaspBMC for an upnp device is grayed out.

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could give me a tip for getting this to work or at least point me in the right direction.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a programming question.  You might get a better response on [superuser](http://superuser.com)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting up an NFS share from the Ubuntu system? It seems like you've mentioned SFTP, UPnP, but it seems like NFS is the more appropriate protocol here.

I have only used the Pi with a Windows SMB share but I imagine the process isn't terribly different on the Pi side of things (you just select NFS share and put in the details). Here are resources I found specific to Ubuntu:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo

Sidenote: this question probably shouldn't fall within StackOverflow. It's not programming related. Maybe Superuser or Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I initially tried NFS, too, following the very same tutorial you sent to me but I stumbled when I have to start / restart the service with 'sudo service nfs-kernel-server restart'. I always get the following error:

* Stopping NFS kernel daemon                                                                    [ OK ]
 * Unexporting directories for NFS kernel daemon...                                              [ OK ]
 * Not starting NFS kernel daemon: no support in current kernel.

Comment: I did some quick Googling on that last error message. I wonder if these are related:

[Might be old](https://forum.linode.com/viewtopic.php?t=5549)

[Pertains to LXC but suggested UNFS](http://askubuntu.com/questions/281663/not-starting-nfs-kernel-daemon-no-support-in-current-kernel)

Seems like you could try the first link's suggestions, or try using UNFS (a userspace NFS implementation)

Comment: Is your Ubuntu system up-to-date? It seems there was a bug about 4 years ago with this with a certain kernel version.

Something tells me the links I provided won't help you much...UNFS does sound like an OK workaround if you aren't crazy about performance.

If all else fails you could create a Windows (SMB) share on Ubuntu :-/

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Plex Media Server on Ubuntu, and Plex plugin on raspbmc. This way you get better interface and offload processing of video from raspberry pi and as bonus you can render all codecs.